# slider images showing on top of each other instead of side by side

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to make a slideshow with html, css and js. When I add additional slides to my current code they appear under the first slide instead of in a slide show. Can anyone see what is wrong with my code? I want the images to be next to each other like in a slideshow.

```js
function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("slideshow__slide");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  if (n > slides.length) {
    slideIndex = 1;
  }
  if (n < 1) {
    slideIndex = slides.length;
  }
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```css
.slideshow {
  max-width: 1000px;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
}
.slideshow__slide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="slideshow">
  <section class="slideshow__slide slide">
    <figure class="slide__bg">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" />
      <figcaption>caption</figcaption>
    </figure>
    <div class="slide__content">
      <a href="#" class="cta">
        <h2 class="cta__title">Sale</h2>
        <p class="cta__description">
          Save up to 50% off 
        </p>
        <span class="button button--primary">Shop</span>
      </a>
    </div>
  </section>
  <!-- second slide -->
   <section class="slideshow__slide slide">
    <figure class="slide__bg">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" />
      <figcaption>caption</figcaption>
    </figure>
    <div class="slide__content">
      <a href="#" class="cta">
        <h2 class="cta__title">Sale</h2>
        <p class="cta__description">
          Save up to 50% off 
        </p>
        <span class="button button--primary">Shop</span>
      </a>
    </div>
  </section>
  <!-- Next and previous buttons -->
  <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&lt;</a>
  <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&gt;</a>
</div>
```

Comment: I can't seem to reproduce the issue. For one thing `plusSlides()` is undefined.

Answer (score 1):

Well first of all you did not even create the JavaScript function plusSlides(), but to make them display next to each other, use the CSS code

```
display: inline-block
```

This makes images display next to each other.